# Github Authentication API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, github-api

I've been frustrated in my efforts to find information about this because a lot of the links posted on StackOverflow and elsewhere to related topics are 404'd.  The Github API only says how to do things from the command line, and none of the gems I've found have given this kind of support.  I know, however, that it is possible, because I've seen it done before.

How would I go about getting a user's current Github login information?  That is, if a user is logged into Github, I want to find that out and use some of their user information in my website.  If they are not logged in, I want to connect to Github to log them in.

Is there a gem for this, and if so, what is it and how does it work (if there isn't sufficient documentation)?  If there isn't, then how do I go about using the Github API to do this in Ruby?

Comment: Use Google's Cache to see what the site was at the last time it was cached.

Comment: If GitHub has pulled the files, then I would assume that the API functionality descriptions int hem are no longer valid.

Comment: In the past I have used [Ghee](https://github.com/rauhryan/ghee) for connecting Rails apps to Github.

Comment: Good stuff.  Is there a way to see if a user is already logged into Github and, if so, use their authentication, like facebook does?  I doubt it, but just checking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For authenticating with github, use the excellent [omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/) gem with the (offcial) [omniauth-github strategy](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-github).

You can see what basic information about the user you will get when the user authenticates with github [here](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-github/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/github.rb).

And here is a [list of omniauth strategies](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/List-of-Strategies) that people have posted. For a good [getting-started example](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook), see the facebook strategy.

Comment: As Mateusz Konieczny points out (extracted from answer): You can also use: [introduction proposed in ignored PR](https://github.com/testbrian/omniauth-github/blob/9d71783e0153a2b940d196c14ea5596f11e124ec/README.md) ([PR is ignored since February 2015](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-github/pull/50))

Answer (score 2):

I found this blog post on using the [Omniauth-Github](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-github) gem.  Provides a great tutorial top to bottom.

I used it today with no issues.  Blog Post: [Omniauth-Github Tutorial](http://natashatherobot.com/rails-omniauth-github-tutorial/)